# Javascript hide/unhide text

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble figuring this out. After a user clicks Link1 I would like it to close when Link2 has been clicked using Javascript. I have seen an example or two with this working in jquery, but I already have a tone of code written using this method, so I would prefer to to have to start all over.Thanks everyone!

HTML...

```
<style>
.hidden { display: none; }
.visible { display: block; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="col2">
 <a href="javascript:unhide('contentONE');">Link 1</a>
 <div id="contentONE" class="hidden">
  <h3>contentONE</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#nogo">Content1.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nogo">Content1.2</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="col2">
 <a href="javascript:unhide('contentTWO');">Link 2</a>
 <div id="contentTWO" class="hidden">
  <h3>contentTWO</h3>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#nogo">Content2.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#nogo">Content2.2</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function unhide(divID) {
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
      item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: unhidden?? you mean 'visible'..?

Comment: Actually, your code seems to work: [link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8TDL5/) The text is showing and disappearing. Or what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I would like link1 content to hide, after link2 has been clicked. Right now you have to click twice to get it to hide again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var collapsables = document.getElementsByClassName('collapsable');

function unhide(divID) {

    // Hide previous
    for (var i = 0; i < collapsables.length; i++) {
        collapsables[i].className = 'collapsable hidden';
    }

    // Show new
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
        item.className = 'collapsable';
    }
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MLmXa/

Comment: Is there a fix for ie8 and ie7?